# Javascript not replacing single character

Tags: javascript, string

This code does not work

```
var x ='hello';
x[2] ='a';
```

Why doesn't it work?
I am not using the replace() function

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the strings are immutable, you cannot change the string using index. 
The string manipulation methods such as trim, slice return new strings.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of legacy behavior of promoting `string` values to `String` object wrappers with the value of the primitive `string` value.

So for example

```
"xyz".charAt(0)
```

is at least notionally evaluated as

```
(new String("xyz")).charAt(0)
```

because `charAt` is a prototype method of `String` objects and can be applied to a primitive string value in this manner.

The down side is that the promoted String object is never stored anywhere and, *even if modified in JavaScript* is immediately discarded. This is what is happening in the code posted:

```
var x ='hello';
x[2] ='a';
```

is treated as

```
new String(x)[2] = 'a'
```

followed by discarding the String object which, incidentally, has a property named `2` with value `'a'`.

The general solution to this is to run JavaScript in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/strict_mode), so that any attempt  to assign a property to a primitive value which has been promoted to an object wrapper generates an error:

```js
"use strict"

var x ='hello';
x[2] ='a';
```